# AttributeError: module 'arcpy' has no attribute 'mapping'

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, export, pdf

I am trying to export a map to PDF and having some difficulty. Right now I am trying to use

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(petrol_address+"/tester.mxd")
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, petrol_address+"/tester.pdf")
```

I am guessing the lack of mapping is due to the ArcGIS Pro version I have (2.8.8). Is there another way I can export my current map and all its layers to a or multiple PDFs?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 6):

I recommend you read [Migrating from arcpy.mapping to ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/mapping/migratingfrom10xarcpymapping.htm).

There are a few things you need to be aware of, particularly:

> **`arcpy.mapping` is now `arcpy.mp`**
>
> The changes introduced with ArcGIS Pro
> were significant enough to merit a module name space change.

In addition to the change to `arcpy.mp`. ArcGIS Pro uses a project file (.aprx) not a map document (.mxd).

> **The ArcGIS Pro project file (.aprx)**
>
> The first and most obvious change is that arcpy.mp in ArcGIS Pro needs
> to reference a project file (.aprx) rather than a map document (.mxd).
> Therefore, you need to replace `arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_path)`
> with `arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(aprx_path)`.

If you are trying to export an MXD, you'll need to import it into your APRX

> The `ArcGISProject` class also has an
> `importDocument` method that allows you to automate the importing of map
> (.mxd), globe (.3dd), scene (.sxd), and other document files into a
> project.

And `arcpy.mp` doesn't have an `ExportToPDF` function:

> **Export functions have moved**
>
> The stand-alone export functions are now
> methods on the [Layout](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/mapping/layout-class.htm) and [MapFrame](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/mapping/mapframe-class.htm) objects.

Answer (score 1):

The module arcpy.mapping now is called arcpy.mp, since launch of ArcGIS Pro.

[Migrating from arcpy.mapping to ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/migratingfrom10xarcpymapping.htm)

Comment: arcpy.mp is a new module in ArcGIS Pro and not just a renaming of arcpy.mapping from ArcMap.

Comment: That's not what i said, what i said is now the module is "named" not that i just changed the name. However, in the documentation itself, it is said that the amount of improvements and changes made it necessary to change the name:

"Arcpy.mapping is now arcpy.mp
The changes introduced with ArcGIS Pro were significant enough to merit a module name space change. The new name offers more flexibility in terms of the capabilities that arcpy.mp offers. For example, in addition to map automation, arcpy.mp also provides project-level management."

Comment: Although not stated explicitly, I think your answer is easily read as implying that it’s no or little more than a module rename.